# How to choose three random, non-overlapping subnets in Python according to a specific range?

Tags: python

I have to choose three random subnets in a specific network. The network itself will always have a /24 subnet mask (I always use 10.10.127.0 for testing purposes). These random subnets can have a /25 subnet mask, all the way up to /29. Now the toughest nut to crack is the overlapping of the subnets. The code you see below might look poorly written, but it does the job.

HOWEVER there is only 1 exception: when the first two non-overlapping subnets are chosen, and one of them is in the 10.10.127.0/25 range and the other in the 10.10.127.128/25 range, I get an infinite loop whenever the third subnet which gets chosen has a /25 subnet mask. Which makes sense of course, both of the previously chosen subnets are already in both /25 subnet ranges.

My question for you guys is: how can I solve this problem and also improve the code? As stated before, the code looks poorly written, however I'm not a good programmer and I'm still trying to learn as much as I can to improve my skills.

```
import random
from netaddr import *
import itertools

def getRandomIP(networkIp=raw_input("Enter the desired network: ")):
   chosenSubnets = []
   network = networkIp + '/24'
   ip = IPNetwork(network)
   print ip

   def subnetOverlap(randomSubnet1, randomSubnet2):
      return (randomSubnet1.first <= randomSubnet2.last and
              randomSubnet2.first <= randomSubnet1.last)

   for randomNumber in random.sample(range(25, 30), 3):
       subnetList = list(ip.subnet(randomNumber))

       restartLoop = True
       while restartLoop:
           restartLoop = False
           for subnet in random.sample(subnetList, 1):
               chosenSubnets.append(subnet)

               for pair in itertools.combinations(chosenSubnets , 2):
                   if subnetOverlap(IPNetwork(pair[0]),
                                    IPNetwork(pair[1])) == True:
                       print 'OVERLAP'
                       chosenSubnets.pop()
                       restartLoop = True
                       print chosenSubnets
                       break
               print subnet

getRandomIP()
```

Comment: So you're trying to generate 3 overlapping subnets. How are these terms defined exactly? What condition are you trying to satisfy?

Comment: You say this goes into an infinite loops sometimes. For question such as this, you need to provide code which clearly demonstrates the problem, which is difficult to do with something that accepts user input and then uses `random` to generate values. I suggest you seed the random number generator with a hardcoded value and specify an argument value to `getRandomIP()` that together will cause this to happen. It may also help you debug the code yourself.

Comment: Incidentally normally you wouldn't put a function inside another function. You could pull you subnetOverlap function outside of your getRandomIP function.

Comment: But I digress. Why don't you 1. Generate the first subnet; 2. While 1: Generate another subnet, and if it's overlapping with the first break out the loop. 3. While 1: Generate another subnet, and if it's overlapping with the first two, break out the loop. 4. Return your result

Comment: Thanks for the feedback so far. @DrXorile, I'm actually already following those steps. I generate the first subnet, then generate the second and compare them. If an overlap is present, I break out of the loop and generate another subnet that does not overlap. Once that's done, I generate the last subnet and check if it's overlapping with the first two (combinations does the job for me). If none of them overlap, the whole script stops.

Comment: However when I'm faced with the following output: [IPNetwork('10.10.127.240/28'), IPNetwork('10.10.127.0/27'), IPNetwork('10.10.127.0/25')], I get into an infinite loop. Simply because the first subnet is in the 10.10.127.128/25 range and the second in the 10.10.127.0/25 range. And that is the problem.

Comment: Okay, I see that now. So can you explain the failure case in a bit more detail?

Comment: Absolutely! There's only one possible failure. The first subnet is generated, let's say 10.10.127.240/28, which is unintentionally also part of the 10.10.127.128/25 range. The second subnet is then generated, let's say 10.10.127.32/27, which is unintentionally also part of the 10.10.127.0/25 range. These don't overlap so the third subnet is generated. The failure occurs when the third subnet is either 10.10.127.0/25 or 10.10.127.128/25, simply because both /25 subnets will always overlap with the other two. So when the first two subnets are each a part of one of both /25 ranges, it fails.

Comment: Specifically is it the subnetOverlap that's giving wrong results (example?) or the loop logic

Comment: It's definitely the loop logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to emulate what I considered to be your original intent.  Specifically, I

1. generate 3 *distinct* numbers from 25 to 29 to generate 3 subnetLists,
2. chose one element from each of them,
3. check that the 3 are not overlapping pairwise.
4. If they are I go back to 1.  If not I return them.

Specifically, a number of changes from your code could be highlighted:

- subnetOverlap is separated out of the getRandomIP
- I call just the pairs into subnetOverlap (I'm not sure why you'd need to call IPNetwork there, but it seems redundant)
- I return the chosenSubnets, rather than print them, and then print them from the function call
- I have a default networkIp that is the usual address you test.  Change the commenting if you want your raw_input back.  But I'd definitely put the raw_input either outside or inside the function, not as a default variable where you had it.

Hope that helps.

```
import random
from netaddr import *
import itertools

def subnetOverlap(randomSubnet1, randomSubnet2):
    return (randomSubnet1.first <= randomSubnet2.last and
          randomSubnet2.first <= randomSubnet1.last)


def getRandomIP(networkIp="10.10.127.240"):
    network = networkIp + '/24'
    ip = IPNetwork(network)
    print ip

    while 1:
        chosenSubnets = []
        overlap = False
        #Choose 3 random subnetLists
        for randomNumber in random.sample(range(25,30),3):
            subnetList = list(ip.subnet(randomNumber))

            #For each subnetList choose a subnet
            chosenSubnets.append(random.sample(subnetList,1)[0])

        #Check whether any pairs overlap
        for pair in itertools.combinations(chosenSubnets,2):
            if subnetOverlap(pair[0],pair[1]):
                print "OVERLAP"
                overlap = True
                break

        #No overlaps found
        if overlap==True: continue
        if overlap==False: break

    #print chosenSubnets
    return chosenSubnets

#networkIp = raw_input("Enter the desired network: ")
for i in range(20):
    print "***************************"
    print getRandomIP("10.10.127.240")
    #getRandomIP(networkIp)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, Dr Xorile! It's definitely an improvement of the code. However, it's not entirely working yet. I'll probably have to make a few adjustment so the overlaps never occur. Right now I still have an occasional overlap.

Comment: Can you give an example? If your overlap function is working, I can't see a way to do it

Comment: Apologies.  Amateur hour!  The continue was continuing in the for loop not the while loop.  I've corrected it.

Comment: Aaaah of course! Didn't have much time to think about it today but that was indeed the problem. I've got my answer now and I can't thank you enough!

Comment: Nothing but a pleasure.  Please mark up the answer too!